# To learn more from someone

Tags: phrase, expression

I've been trying to formulate this idea in the most natural-sounding way possible.

A professor has accepted to teach me more about a topic I'm passionate about and that she's personally familiar with in private. I want to express that I'm looking forward to learn about this topic with her. So far my attempts give more of the idea that I'm looking forward to learn *about* her.

> "Ich freue mich darauf, von Ihnen zu erfahren/lernen."

I'm assuming the correct equivalent expression that I'm aiming for uses a totally different wording, but I don't know what to use in place of *von Ihnen*. How do I achieve the right connotation?

Answer (score 3):

Almost. You need a *mehr darüber* and likely want a *schon*.

> Ich freue mich (schon) darauf, von Ihnen mehr darüber zu lernen.

That *mehr darüber* refers back to your previous knowledge, as you sure want to assert that the professor won't waste her time with a beginner.